Finding critical points of a Morse function on an implicit manifold
In the special case that a manifold is given by some implicit equation
$$ F(x_0, x_1, \dots, x_N) = 0$$
Then a natural Morse function is to simply take $f(p) = X_i$, where $p = (X_0, X_1, \cdots X_i, \cdots , X_N)$ and $F(p) = 0$
Now it seems that to identify if $f^{-1}(X_i)$ is a critical level set, I just need to take the normalized gradient of $F$ at every $p \in f^{-1}(X_i)$
$$ \widehat{\nabla F(p)} = \frac{ \nabla F}{\lVert \nabla F \rVert} \Big \rvert_{p}$$
and check that it is proportional to $\mathbf{e_i}$, that is, $ \lvert \widehat{\nabla F(p)} \cdot \mathbf{e_i} \rvert = 1 $ for at least some $p \in f^{-1}(X_i)$
Is this correct? Is this as simple as it gets for this case, or is there a simpler method?
